# Using BETWEEN and begins_with in a single query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to introduce an access pattern to an existing table and am unsure whether I can retrieve the data I want using a single query. I need to retrieve all records which include `paddedProperty1` and `paddedProperty2`. Neither are their own attribute and only contained within the sortKey. The `paddedId` can be within a range of 000000 to 999999. The uuid suffix is unknown at the time of query. The first 3 parts are padded to facilitate `begins_with` queries.

How to incorporate the ranged components (id) and an unknown `uuid` into a single query? The sortKey looks like `paddedId#paddedProperty1#paddedProperty2#uuid` (uuid is generated from short-uuid lib).

Using the `BETWEEN` operator enables to solve the problem with `paddedId`, however it requires to know the entirety of the sort key and I don't as the `uuid` suffix is unknown. I don't care about the `uuid` suffix, but cannot figure out how to include the `BETWEEN` logic with `begins_with` to facilitate the `paddedId`.

Answer (score 0):

The BETWEEN values you provide don't have to actually exist in the database, so you can pick marker values that must exist before or after any legit value you're going to encounter.

For example, if you want to use the BETWEEN operator to find every word in the dictionary starting with B, you can ask for "BETWEEN B and BZZZZZZZZZZZZ". You don't know the actual final word starting with B but it's alphabetically ahead of that one!

I don't 100% understand what you're asking for but I feel like this fact will help you with your answer.